# Object recognition in 3D images

Tags: object, 3d, detection

I have a 3D video that I have broken down into single images in 7 different planes. I am wondering what tools can I use for object detection. I read that OpenCV might not be the right tool for that, what could I use instead?

Regards

Aleksej

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can be used for segmentation on 3D data as long as it can be represented as a depth map (normally the information of the Z-axis in camera coordinate).

If you have depth data as a cv::Mat, you can run segmentation (region-growing, watershed, etc) on the depth data to get segmented objects.

It is assumed that the edges are distinguishable and unique between objects ofcourse.

As a pre-processing step, you can also smoothen the edges with some morphological operations to make the segmentation better.